# How can I parse m3u8 playlist to retrieve the url of .ts chunks?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, playlist, m3u8

This is `m3u8` link url :

```
https://thr-pltv-4.aionet.ir/hls.m3u8?mwk=89374692478207427715317283451977223330&s=59560951766264806007645747993639236956&client=videojs&version=4.12
```

And this is `m3u8` file plain text :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-VERSION:3

#EXTINF:10.0000,
hls/slide/225_0_4_51_30511_150776_1.ts?
s=59560951766264806007645747993639236956&client=videojs
#EXTINF:10.0000,
hls/slide/225_0_4_51_30511_1105440_2.ts?
s=59560951766264806007645747993639236956&client=videojs
#EXTINF:10.0000,
hls/slide/225_0_4_51_30511_2082664_3.ts?
s=59560951766264806007645747993639236956&client=videojs
```

Please just tell me how can I make the links to `ts` segment files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install a HTTP client on your machine
   Let's assume you are on Windows. Use 'wget' from  http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/
2. open a command prompt in Windows
3. call wget -O chunk_1.ts "https://thr-pltv-4.aionet.ir/hls/slide/225_0_4_51_30511_150776_1.ts?
   s=59560951766264806007645747993639236956&client=videojs"